# Why hide() and show() functions does not work in a loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this JS code which iterates through a div and triggers an ajax call for each. The ajax call is running fine. But I would like to show and hide a 'progress bar' during the each loop.

My html code is:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" id="waiting" style="display: none">
                <div style="width: 100%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info">
                    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This html code is good (because when I erase the style 'display:none', then I see the progress bar).

My JS code is:

```
$('#btn_valider_paris').click(function() {
   
    var _token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr( 'content' );
    var token_parieur = $('#token_parieur').val();
    
    // @todo : l'animation n'apparait pas , à creuser + tard.
    $('#waiting').show();
    
    $('#div_liste_questions').children('.form-inline').each(function() {
        
        // alert('id_question = '+$(this).data('id_question') + ' / ' + $(this).data('id_type_question')    ) ;
        var id_question = $(this).data('id_question');
        var id_type_question = $(this).data('id_type_question');
        var numeric_entier = $(this).find('.numeric_partie_entiere').val();
        var numeric_decimal = $(this).find('.numeric_partie_decimale').val();
        var text = $(this).find('.text').val();
        var match_score_equipe1 = $(this).find('.match_score_equipe1').val();
        var match_score_equipe2 = $(this).find('.match_score_equipe2').val();
        var liste_reponse = $(this).find('.liste_reponse').val();
      
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: $('#url_for_ajax').val() + '/post_enregistrer_pari_question_ajax',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                _token: _token, 
                token_parieur: token_parieur, 
                id_question: id_question, 
                id_type_question: id_type_question,
                numeric_entier: numeric_entier,
                numeric_decimal: numeric_decimal,
                text: text,
                match_score_equipe1:match_score_equipe1,
                match_score_equipe2:match_score_equipe2,
                liste_reponse:liste_reponse
            },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      
                if(data.code_retour === -1){
                     toastr["error"](data.texte_retour);
                } 
        
            }
        });
                 
    });
    
    $('#waiting').show();
   
         
});
```

The **$('#waiting').show()** and **$('#waiting').hide()** have no effects at all. And no error message in the console.

What might be wrong in my code with these ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drive a progress thermometer, you need a couple of counters and some simple logic around them.

Here's the sort of pattern that should work for you (bulky code removed) :

```
$('#btn_valider_paris').click(function() {
    var _token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr( 'content' );
    var token_parieur = $('#token_parieur').val();
    var ajaxCalls = { total:0, complete:0 }; // <<<<< initialize two counters
    $('#div_liste_questions').children('.form-inline').each(function() {
        // var ..., ... etc.
        jQuery.ajax({
            // etc, etc.
        }).then(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if(data.code_retour === -1) {
                toastr.error(data.texte_retour);
            }
        }, function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus || errorThrown);
        }).always(function() { // .always fires on both success and error.
            ajaxCalls.complete++; // <<<<< count ajax completions asynchronously, as the responses arrive.
            console.log(ajaxCalls.total, ajaxCalls.complete); 
            // Here, set progress thermometer to indicate that "ajaxCalls.complete of ajaxCalls.total" are complete.
            if(ajaxCalls.complete === ajaxCalls.total) {
                $('#waiting').hide(); // <<<<< hide #waiting when all calls are complete.
            }
        });
        ajaxCalls.total++; // <<<<< count ajax calls synchronously, as the calls are made.
    });
    if(ajaxCalls.total > 0) {
        // Here, initialise the progress thermometer to indicate that "0 of ajaxCalls.total" are complete.
        $('#waiting').show();
    } else {
        $('#waiting').hide();
    }
});
```

Note in particular that :

- `ajaxCalls.total` is incremented synchronously in the `.each()` loop
- `ajaxCalls.complete` is incremented asynchronously, as the responses arrive.

Comment: I have understood, I will apply that tonight. Merci

Answer (score 0):

it could be the inline style is overriding it, why not set the state in the function?

You can also use

```
$('#waiting').css('display','none');
$('#waiting').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use beforeSend to show that div before every call.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: $('#url_for_ajax').val() + '/post_enregistrer_pari_question_ajax',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    $('#waiting').show();
  }
  data: {
     _token: _token, 
     token_parieur: token_parieur, 
     id_question: id_question, 
     id_type_question: id_type_question,
     numeric_entier: numeric_entier,
     numeric_decimal: numeric_decimal,
     text: text,
     match_score_equipe1:match_score_equipe1,
     match_score_equipe2:match_score_equipe2,
     liste_reponse:liste_reponse
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

      if(data.code_retour === -1){
        toastr["error"](data.texte_retour);
      } 

    }
  });
```